# Powershell. Write event logs

Tags: powershell, scripting, ps

I have a script which moves some files from a folder to the temp folder, archives them and cleans the temp folder at the end.

I want my script to also write information about it in the win-event log.

Here is my script:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test1\ | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "09/24/2018 09:00 PM"} | Move-Item -Destination C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\
Compress-Archive -path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\ -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data1\test.zip
Remove-Item C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\*
```

I want to add code which will write an event for any error into the win-event log.

Comment: Writing an eventlog entry is as simple as: Write-EventLog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, you can use `Write-EventLog` to write to the Windows Event Logs. If you want to write any errors that occur during those commands, then you probably want to use a `Try..Catch` to catch any errors and handle them:

```
Try {
    $PrevEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test1\ | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "09/24/2018 09:00 PM"} | Move-Item -Destination C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\
    Compress-Archive -path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\ -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data1\test.zip
    Remove-Item C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\data\* 
Catch {
    Write-Error $_

    $ErrorEvent = @{
        LogName = 'Application'
        Source = 'YourScript'
        EventID = 123
        EntryType = 'Information'
        Message = $_
    }
    Write-EventLog @ErrorEvent
}
Finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = $PrevEAP
}
```

In order for an exception (error) to trigger a `Try..Catch` the exception needs to be terminating (vs non-terminating). You can force cmdlets to do terminating errors by setting the cmdlets `-ErrorAction` to `Stop`, or you can do this globally via the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.

In the catch block, the error is held in the special variable: `$_`. So we can use `Write-Error` to still write it out to the console (if you want to) and then we're using `Write-EventLog` to write it into the Event Log.

Customise LogName, Source, EventID, Information etc. as per your needs. Note LogName needs to be one of the existing Logs and Entry Type needs to be one of the valid entry types (Information, Warning, Error).